# How to add Local jar file as dependency for classpath in dependencies of buildscript

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

```
buildscript{
   repositories{
   }
   dependencies{
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

   }
}
```

How can I add a local **gradle-1.3.1.jar** as dependency to **classpath** instead of above  declaration?